# I'm trying to make a group of cells in processing and I want to transmit data from one to the other as they get close to each other

Tags: processing

I've got code but it won't even slightly work does anyone have any sort of an idea??
I don't need efficiency I just need some sort of idea.

Comment: please attach your code so people can help

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer general "how do I do this" type questions. You'll have much better luck if you ask a specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type question instead.

But I can help in a general sense:

First off, you need to [break your problem down into smaller steps](http://HappyCoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and take on those steps one at a time. Can you create a simple program that just shows two hardcoded circles that change color when they get near each other? You'll have to use basic circle-circle [collision detection](http://HappyCoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection).

You probably also want to [create classes](http://HappyCoding.io/tutorials/processing/creating-classes) that encapsulate your data. You might have a `Cell` class that encapsulates the data and behavior of one cell.

When you have that working, then you can think about your overall design. You might loop over every `Cell`, and then find out which other `Cell` instances are nearby. When you have that, then you can think about transmitting data between them. You'd do this by calling a function on the instance.

Here's some pseudo-code:

```
for(every Cell thisCell in cells){
   for(every Cell otherCell in cells){
      if(thisCell is near otherCell){
         otherCell.setData(thisCell.data);
      }
   }
}
```

That's just the general idea though. The specifics of exactly how you approach each step are up to you. If you do get stuck on a specific step, please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a new question, and we'll go from there. Good luck.